# DDNS unix device in 10.x network

Tags: vpn, dynamic-dns, dyndns

My Internet provider uses NAT network to connect users. So, when I connect to the Internet, I got an `10.x.x.x` IP address.

Is there any way to access Unix device in such type of network?
DDNS needs an external IP to get work, and I can't get it, even if I want.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: And of course, the best solution is to get constant connection to the device.

Comment: Errr.... ask you ISP to provide you a routable IP address? Either that or to stop pretending they're selling Internet access. Other than that, best option is a tunnel of some sort (often a VPN). Other solutions include some out-of-band method (e.g., attach a modem and dial in). We'd need more details to provide recommendations...

Comment: All of my previous ISP gave an external IP, not fixed, but public... This one gives `10.x.x.x` or you should pay some fabulous money for the fixed IP. I have, for example, BtSync which I would like to get work.

Comment: if they won't give you a routable (possibly dynamic) IP, either v4 or v6 (if you have v6 connectivity everywhere you need it), then you'd have to check if a VPN with a routable IP is cheaper...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your external IP (to your local network) is a non-routable address (10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16) then you cannot do this.  DDNS provides a name->ip mapping but your bigger problem is that you are behind NAT.  For inbound connections to work you need forwarding rules on the NAT gateway, which if your ISP doesn't give you a real IP they aren't going to do.

If your ISP won't give you a public address and you can't switch to a provider that does, you can still get around this issue.  To do so you need a host on the internet you can establish a tunnel to so you can route traffic into your LAN.

Comment: The first paragraph is fully correct. I understand this. For me, the magic begins with the second paragraph. Do I need to have only host or I should have some server to route traffic?

Comment: @kot-6eremot You need to have access to some other machine with a public IP address, e.g. a VPS. Or you need to use a proxy service; depending on what you want to do, one or the other may end up being cheaper/faster/easier.

Comment: @kot-6eremot If I were in your place I'd get a cheap VPS with static addressing, start an ssh tunnel from my LAN gateway to the VPS and then  run  NAT on the VPS and forward traffic over the tunnel.

Comment: @casey Aha, now I understood all things around this problem. Thanks a lot for the consultation =)